# PHP equivalent of uniqid() in C#

Tags: c#, php

trying to duplicate some PHP code in C#.  The PHP code uses the uniqid function with the more entropy parameter set to true.  Any idea of how to best duplicate this in C#?

https://www.php.net/uniqid

Comment: Is this similar to GUID in .NET terms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

something like:

```
string uniqid(string prefix, bool more_entropy) {
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix)) 
      prefix = string.Empty;

    if (!more_entropy) {
      return (prefix + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Left(13);
    } else {
      return (prefix + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Left(23);
    }
 }
```

Edit: To reflect comments

This is a very simple *off the top of my head* solution, and I'd suggest that for a more rigorous solution you'd investigate proper 'random' number' generation such as via System.Math namespace directly. Please see these other [SO questions and answers on random number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=random+c%23).

System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

Will give you a unique string.

Comment: Thank you so much - thats kind of what I was thinking but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Keep in mind that only the entire Guid is supposed to be almost-certainly unique. That's not necessarily true for a portion of its string representation. See http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx

Comment: String.Left() would be String.Substring() in C#

Answer (score 14):

After some googling I found how PHP's uniqid works and implemented it in c#:

```
private string GetUniqID()
{
    var ts = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));
    double t = ts.TotalMilliseconds / 1000;

    int a = (int)Math.Floor(t);
    int b = (int)((t - Math.Floor(t)) * 1000000);

    return a.ToString("x8") + b.ToString("x5");
}
```

This code provides the exact same result, the only difference is that extra parameters of uniqid() are not implemented.

Comment: It does not provides the exact same result. If you call this function within a loop, multiple duplicated ids will be generated as long as doing same in php, all ids will be unique.